# Cypress is returning an empty array when trying to log sheetnames of an excel file

Tags: excel, cypress

I am currently trying to get the sheetnames of an excel file but Cypress is returning an empty array. Is there something I missed? I'll be using it to verify data on later steps.

I'm using Cypress 9.6.0 with Cucumber. Below are my scripts and screenshots:

`index.js` for task

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
on('file:preprocessor', cucumber());
on('task', { 
  checkExcelSheetContents(args){
    if (fs.existsSync(args.filePath)) {
      const workbook = xlsx.readFile(args.filePath);
      return xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.SheetNames)
      } else {
        throw new Error ("File not found")
      }
  }
  })
return Object.assign({}, config, {
  fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures',
  integrationFolder: 'cypress/integration',
  screenshotsFolder: 'cypress/screenshots',
  videosFolder: 'cypress/videos',
  supportFile: 'cypress/support/index.js'
  });
```

}

`.js` file

```js
And ('try', () => {
        var excelFilePath = "../CreateAutomatedTests/cypress/downloads/courses20220714_09_51_27.xlsx"
        cy.wrap(excelFilePath).as('filePath')
    
    cy.get('@filePath').then((filePath) => {
        cy.task('checkExcelSheetContents', { filePath }).then((contents) => {
            cy.log(contents)
            })
        })
})
```

**Please see these screenshots as well**

[image: Cypress UI result]

[image: Sheet names]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used the buffer version of `xlsx.read()`.

From [xlsx package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

> For Node ESM, the readFile helper is not enabled. Instead, fs.readFileSync should be used to read the file data as a Buffer for use with XLSX.read:
>
> ```js
> import { readFileSync } from "fs";
> import { read } from "xlsx/xlsx.mjs";
>
> const buf = readFileSync("test.xlsx");
> /* buf is a Buffer */
> const workbook = read(buf);
> ```

Your task:

```js
on('task', { 
  checkExcelSheetContents(args){
    if (fs.existsSync(args.filePath)) {
      const buf = fs.readFileSync(file);
      const workbook = xlsx.read(buf, { type: 'buffer' });
      return workbook.SheetNames
    } else {
      throw new Error ("File not found")
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried the buffer but I am still getting the empty array :/ Here is my task:
on('task', { 
      checkExcelSheetContents(args){
        if (fs.existsSync(args.filePath)) {
          const buf = fs.readFileSync(args.filePath);
          const workbook = xlsx.read(buf, { type: 'buffer' });
          return xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.SheetNames)
          } else {
            throw new Error ("File not found")
          }
      }
      })

Comment: I got a result with `return workbook.SheetNames`.